# How to create a class - function for astype function python?

Tags: python, oop

There are lot of columns in dataframe like :

```
   df_train_data['material'] = df_train_data['material'].astype('category',ordered=False)
   df_train_data['aircon'] = df_train_data['aircon'].astype('category',ordered=False)
   df_train_data['building_quality'] = df_train_data['building_quality'].astype('category',ordered=True)
   df_train_data['fireplace'] = df_train_data['fireplace'].astype('category',ordered=False)
   .
   .
   .
   df_test_data.....
```

For both train and test dataframes.
So, instead of writing 20 - 30 odd lines for each column in train and each in test again, How to write them in a function where we can pass only the column names (comma separated) and ordered as an argument in a function?

I can only think of one way : ( new to programming)

```
  def data_type(df_name,col,ord_type):
      return df_name[col] = df_name[col].astype('category',ordered = ord_type)
```

How to do this for multiple column names at once?

Comment: there's an easy way to set type, the only thing that gets into the way is different `ordered` param.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your answer is working for multiple columns, just use lists instead of single values :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def data_type(df_name,col,ord_type):
      return df_name[col].astype('category',ordered = ord_type)

cols = ['a', 'b']

df[cols] = data_type(df, cols, [True, False])
```

df is now :

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

with dtypes :

```
a    category
b    category
c       int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: df.dtypes of this dataframe df is : a    int32, b    int32. This shouldve changed to category

Comment: I have changed my answer to set the new column to the original dataframe. Using df.dtypes you can see the types are 'category' for column a and b as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It may help

```
data = pd.read_excel(r"<file_location>.xlsx")
def data_type(df, as_type, ordered, *cols):
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(as_type, ordered=False)
    return df

df = data_type(data, 'category', 'False', data.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks JON, this works too!. and it can work without the for loop in the function as well.!

Answer (score 1):

If focusing only on setting/changing type for a large number of columns (all columns) at once for several dataframes: [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) allows passing a `dict of column name -> data type` (as a 1st argument):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

...
df_train_data.astype(dict(zip_longest(df_train_data.columns, ('category',), fillvalue='category')))
df_test_data.astype(dict(zip_longest(df_test_data.columns, ('category',), fillvalue='category')))
```

Comment: but what about ordered = true/false ?

Comment: @Viv, that's why I mentioned *If focusing only on setting/changing type*. You may use it as alternative if needed

Comment: Understood, thanks I will be using same syntax for fillna, dropna etc functions.